# RabbitMQ Java Client - Slow Consumer leads to connection closing

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I've detected many "Broken Pipe" or "Connection refused" errors in my application using RabbitMQ Java Driver `amqp-client` version `5.1.2`. RabbitMQ Server version is `3.7.3`.

To throttle the incoming messages, i'll just put a `Thread.sleep(2000)` loop into `DefaultConsumer` with `autoAck=0`. Sure, i could set `channel.basicQos(..)`, but i need to throttle with more than just "how many messages do i have currently".

However, this pseudo code leads to `java.net.SocketException`:

```
// register new connection
// register new channel / consumer for receiving messages which waits for 2 seconds on each handleDelivery
// sleep for 60 seconds (main-thread) and let the consumer do its job
// register new channel (for writing)
```

And another case would be that after sleeping several minutes in `handleDelivery`, a connection is reset / broken pipe / etc. But let's focus on the first case with the pseudo code.

This leads to the following stacktrace when creating the second channel, which also uses the first connection.

```
java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at java.io.DataOutputStream.flush(DataOutputStream.java:123)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandler.flush(SocketFrameHandler.java:177)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.flush(AMQConnection.java:559)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQCommand.transmit(AMQCommand.java:127)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.quiescingTransmit(AMQChannel.java:447)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.quiescingTransmit(AMQChannel.java:429)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.quiescingRpc(AMQChannel.java:346)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.rpc(AMQChannel.java:337)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.privateRpc(AMQChannel.java:277)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:138)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.open(ChannelN.java:133)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelManager.createChannel(ChannelManager.java:176)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.createChannel(AMQConnection.java:542)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringConnection.createChannel(AutorecoveringConnection.java:108)
    at myapp.rabbitmq.RabbitMQPool.registerChannel(RabbitMQPool.java:232)
    at myapp.rabbitmq.RabbitMQPool.registerChannel(RabbitMQPool.java:200)
    at myapp.rabbitmq.RabbitMQPool.registerWriteOnlyChannel(RabbitMQPool.java:185)
    at myapp.rabbitmq.RabbitMQPool.registerWriteOnlyChannel(RabbitMQPool.java:181)
    at myapp.MyMainClass.start(MyMainClass.java:110)
    at myapp.MyMainClass.main(MyMainClass.java:46)
```

When, however, i don't wait 2 seconds at each `handleDelivery`, creating the second queue will be created just fine. Why?

These are the parameters for creating a new connection:

```
ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
factory.setPort(5672);
factory.setHost("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx");
factory.setUsername("user");
factory.setPassword("pass");
factory.setAutomaticRecoveryEnabled(true);
factory.setConnectionTimeout(0);
Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
```

And the code that builds the channels:

```
if (!connection.isOpen()) {
    // this fires at the second time when first channel consumes with `Thread.sleep(2000)`
}
channel = connection.createChannel();
channel.queueDeclare(channelName, true, false, false, null);
if (consumer != null) { // only the first time
    DefaultConsumer queueingConsumer = new DefaultConsumer(channel) {
        @Override
        public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag, Envelope envelope, AMQP.BasicProperties properties, byte[] body) {
            Thread.sleep(2000)
        }
        ... some more @Overrides
    };
    channel.basicConsume(channelName, autoAck, queueingConsumer);
}
```

RabbitMQ Server logs don't show any errors and also no other errors are thrown. RabbitMQ is connected via LAN and i reproduced the error for dozens of times in both configurations with the same outcome.

I upgraded from driver version `3.5.6` to `5.1.2` and RabbitMQ Server (fresh OS, too) from `3.5.6` to `3.7.3` and the problems began. I thought maybe it'd be possible that `QueueingConsumer` was deprecated and now i have to use `DefaultConsumer`.

Comment: A complete, runnable example would help people such as myself get to the bottom of this. What version of Erlang are you using? FYI, the RabbitMQ team monitors [this mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/rabbitmq-users) and only sometimes answers questions on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i found the solution.

Pausing the consumerthread with `Thread.sleep(...)` doesn't seem to be a good idea.

When i use `basicCancel(...)` on the channel, everything works well and no channel will be closed and no exception will be raised.